# How to view the simulation after running the code on Cygwin?

Tags: cygwin

I am using a MD program called Macsimus, I ran a test simulation, however I cannot see any plot showing up? I see the following comments on Cygwin

showcp is /cygdrive/c/Users/Neena/Desktop/macsimus_2018_09_13/macsimus/bin/showcp
plot is /cygdrive/c/Users/Neena/Desktop/macsimus_2018_09_13/macsimus/bin/plot

Answer (score 1):

From the instruction at http://old.vscht.cz/fch/software/macsimus/

```
Graphics (blend, show, and some utilities) is available for 
basic X11 without any other requirements.
```

This means that you need to install the X Server. Probably for your scope is enough to install the cygwin packages `xinit` and `xterm` and all the other packages will come as dependency.

Comment: I added xinit and xterm, however I still do not see the trajectory

Comment: are you starting the program from xterm instead of mintty (Cygwin Terminal) ?

Comment: I am using a cygwin  terminal

Comment: Try from the XTerm after running the XServer. Mintty is a console program and does not use the X server interface